# SQL Query needed for fetch value from Two identical table but not fully identical table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Suppose we have two tables A and B.

A holds 4 rows and B holds 3 rows.
In table A and B few column values are same so it helps in mapping.

I want to build a query which will fetch all details under table B and will fetch a record from table A which is not in table A.

```
Table A                
001 ABC Tango          
002 XYZ Alpha          
003 PQR Beta           
004 DEF Gamma

Table B
001 ABC Tango Delhi
002 XYZ Alpha Mumbai
003 PQR Beta Pune
```

So I need a query which will give a result as like this

```
001 ABC Tango Delhi
002 XYZ Alpha Mumbai
003 PQR Beta Pune
004 DEF Gamma
```

First three rows are from Table B and last 4th row is from table A as that particular data is not in Table B.

If anyone can build a query for me about this, then please let me know.

Comment: Mysql or ms sql? These are two different products. What have you done so far?

Comment: First try it on your own..just a hint you need to search for types of joins .https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Please write English that can not be interpreted in at least three different ways.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, NULL AS Field4
FROM TableA
WHERE Field1 NOT IN (SELECT Field1 FROM TableB)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM TableB
```

Comment: Note I used UNION I/o LEFT or RIGHT JOIN because then you need to use e.g. ISNULL to determine from which table to get the output field.

Comment: This will return 3 columns, OP wants 4 columns.

Comment: I guess you're right, I misread the "Delhi" as being part of the column with "Tango". Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, the solution if you want to use joins:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TableB.Field1 IS NULL THEN TableA.Field1 ELSE TableB.Field1 END AS Field1
, CASE WHEN TableB.Field1 IS NULL THEN TableA.Field2 ELSE TableB.Field2 END AS Field2
, CASE WHEN TableB.Field1 IS NULL THEN TableA.Field3 ELSE TableB.Field3 END AS Field3
, TableB.Field4
FROM TableB
FULL JOIN TableA ON TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1
```

Comment: Added the 4th column of TableB

Answer (score 0):

Do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
select b.col1, b.col2, b.col3, a.col3
from b
  FULL OUTER JOIN a on a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2
```

Comment: This won't show record 004 DEF Gamma in the output.